# Fixing a python issue with a patch is given as source code instead of dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dll, patch

I am not sure how to fix this, please advice

I have a python security issue which python released a patch for this.
Patch is not released as another new version of dll instead it is released as source only files

Issue : CVE-2020-15523 is an invalid search path in Python

Solution is to update a patch which is a github link

Patch: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/21297

But since I was using a python.dll how should I used this source instead of dll?

Complete issue description  https://mail.python.org/archives/list/security-announce@python.org/thread/C5RIXC2ZIML3NOEIOGFPA6ISGU5L2QXL/

Comment: Where did you get your current python dll from? I would assume they have a newer python binary release already which contains this fix.

Comment: As per the comments, The next patched releases will be 3.9.0b5, 3.8.4, 3.7.9 (source only), 
3.6.12 (source only), it only contains source only, let me know I am wrong?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Where did you get your current python dll from?

Comment: From here https://www.python.org/downloads/ , currently we are using 3.6 version

Comment: Which exact version? 3.6.11 or 3.6.12 or 3.6.13?

Comment: python 3.6.11  version

Comment: I can't find any binaries for 3.6.11 there, only source files.